# How do I filter based on matching keyword?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I filter if header and content contains a matching keyword (example: login), and extract the tabs that have that keyword but categoryName will still be there?

```
export cons Tab = {
  categoryName: "Account Management",
  tabs: [
    {
      header: "How to login?",
      content: "You need to go to the portal..",
    },
    {
      header: "How to forget password?",
      content: "Click on "Forgot password",
    },
  ]
}
```

Example output when keyword is "login":

```
export cons Tab = {
  categoryName: "Account Management",
  tabs: [
    {
      header: "How to login?",
      content: "You need to go to the portal..",
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Tried it but not so sure how to use it :( @Cully

Comment: @Aly So read documentation and check examples. Return when you have tried something

Comment: Do you know how to find out if one string contains another string?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `filter` method from JavaScript, like so:

```js
 const Tab = {
  categoryName: "Account Management",
  tabs: [
    {
      header: "How to login?",
      content: "You need to go to the portal..",
    },
    {
      header: "How to forget password?",
      content: "Click on Forgot password",
    }
  ]
}
 
const filterWithKeyword=(keyword)=>{
  Tab.tabs= Tab.tabs.filter(t => t.header.includes(keyword));
}

filterWithKeyword("login");
console.log(Tab);
```

Comment: add `content.includes` too

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly he wouldn't get the result he wants with the data he have.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to do this in-place. Don't change Tab, create a copy with filtered tabs.

Comment: @AlexanderB. yeah but only if he is using `Tab` as a  `state`, which we don't know so far.

Answer (score -1):

```js
 const Tab = {
  categoryName: "Account Management",
  tabs: [
    {
      header: "How to login?",
      content: "You need to go to the portal..",
    },
    {
      header: "How to forget password?",
      content: "Click on Forgot password",
    }
  ]
}
 
const filterWithKeyword=(keyword)=>{
  Tab.tabs= Tab.tabs.filter(t => t.header.indexOf(keyword)!==-1);
}

filterWithKeyword("login");
console.log(Tab);
```

We can also use indexOf instead of includes .

Comment: You just copied someone else's answer and changed one function call.

Comment: Yes , but I wanted to tell that , it can be done by this method also , as stackoverflow solutions tells us different ways a same question can be solved .

Comment: Yeah, but don't just copy someone else's answer.